# Combine data from two columns into one without affecting the data values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two columns in a data frame. I want to combine those columns into a single column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [500, 200, 13, 47], 'b':['$', '€', .586,.02]})

df
Out: 
             a     b
       0     500   $
       1     200   €
       2     13   .586
       3     47   .02
```

I want to merge that two columns without affecting the data.

Expected output:

```
    df
Out: 
              a     
       0     500$
       1     200€
       2     13.586
       3     47.02
```

Please help me with this...

I tried the below solution, but it does not work for me,

```
df.b=np.where(df.b,df.b,df.a)
df.loc[df['b'] == '', 'b'] = df['a']
```

Answer (score 0):

First solution working with convert both columns to strings and then join with `+`, last convert Series to one column `DataFrame` - but it working only if numbers less like `1` for column `b`:

```
df1 = df.astype(str)
df = (df1.a + df1.b.str.replace(r'^0', '')).to_frame('a')
print (df)
        a
0    500$
1    200€
2  13.586
3   47.02
```

Or if want mixed values numeric for last 2 rows and strings for first 2 rows use:

```
m = df.b.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))

df.loc[m, 'a'] = df.loc[m, 'a'].astype(str) + df.b
df.loc[~m, 'a'] += df.pop('b')
print (df)
        a
0    500$
1    200€
2  13.586
3   47.02
```